# Simply stop script execution upon notice/warning

Tags: php

How may arrange that script execution stops upon notice/warning, without changing other behaviour, inc, the notice/warning messages, i.e. e.g. not throwing an exception.

[Stop script execution upon notice/warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520390/stop-script-execution-upon-notice-warning) is a different question.

Comment: You should stop it yourself... Create a Error Handler or create a function...

Comment: Maybe you can manage it with exceptions (@see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but note: "not throwing an exception."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom error handling function, like so:

```
<?php
// error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_USER_ERROR:    exit('Im a user error.');
        case E_USER_WARNING:  exit('Im a user warning');
        case E_USER_NOTICE:   
              printNotice($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
              break;
        default:              exit('Unknown Error');
    }

    // don't execute PHP internal error handler
    return true;
}

function printNotice($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    // use the following vars to output the original error
    var_dump($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);

    exit;
}
```

Important are the constants: `E_USER_NOTICE` and `E_USER_WARNING`.

The `function printNotice()` shows how you can print the original error,
so that it appears unmodified and then stops script execution with exit.
All the original error data (message, line number, etc.) is in the variables 
$errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline. PHP makes the error data automatically available at the registered errorhandler (here myErrorHandler).
In this example i'm forwarding all the parameters a second time, to  printNotice() function, which could format the error differently or do what you like upon it.

And then register it with [set_error_handler()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), like so:

```
<?php
// register your error handler
set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

In order to test the error handling you might use the function trigger_error():

```
trigger_error("This is a User Error", E_USER_ERROR);
trigger_error("This is a User Warning", E_USER_WARNING);
trigger_error("This is a User Warning", E_USER_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that changes other behaviour. E.g. changes output "Notice: Undefined index..." to "Unknown Error".

Comment: This is just example code. You can place whatever you like in the switch statement. I've modified the code to show that the switch is just a conditional to catch the error .. what you do with it is your thing. The error data is in the variables passed to the error handler. You might just echo them or format them or don't use them at all.

Comment: OK, so the suggestion is to reproduce the in-built message format with user code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward answer to your question is `NO` you can't.
   You have to create a custom error handler that stops execution.
   As there is no way to do this outside.